# HR user does not have access to DBA_TAB_COLUMNS

Tags: sql, oracle

I am studying Oracle Database and solving review questions. 
There is a questions and answer about dictionary views that I do not quite understand:

*You need to get information about columns in a table you do not own, nor do you have privileges to it. Which view can you query to get this information?*

And answer for this questions is: `DBA_TAB_COLUMNS`.

I thought that correct answer would be `Can’t be done`.

I have run it with HR user:

```sql
SELECT * FROM DBA_TAB_COLUMNS;
```

I have got `table or view does not exist` which likely means that HR does not have access to this particular view. Which is in my understanding correct behavior.

Could you please explain why `DBA_TAB_COLUMNS` is the correct answer if it does not work for all users?

Comment: Are the materials you are studying from written by Oracle, or some other source? It seems you understand this stuff better than the authors!

Comment: Hey, thanks, but I don't think so. OCA Oracle Database SQL Exam Guide (Exam 1Z0-071) (Oracle Press) by Steve O'Hearn. I think book is great. I use it in conjunction with other materials

Comment: OK, that's good then. Even the best books sometimes have some questionable things in them (like this particular problem), just making sure the entire book is not like this. To be clear: the answer may not necessarily be "wrong", but it makes an assumption that is very unlikely to be true in real life: you don't have access to another user's table, but instead you DO have access to `DBA_TAB_COLUMNS`. Why would that ever be the case? And in any case, the answer is mum re: the requirement that you must have privileges to this view.

Comment: The question says you don't have access to the table you want to find out about. It doesn't say anything about your dictionary access,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it is correct **if** you have access to `dba_tab_columns`; not everyone does.

Privileged users (such as `SYS` or `SYSTEM`) own the database so they see it. If you can connect as such user (doesn't have to be any of those two; that could be any other user granted required privileges), then you can perform query.

Or, if you can acquire `select` privileges, that would be enough. For example:

Create brand new user with very limited privileges:

```
SQL> connect sys as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> create user mike identified by lion
  2  default tablespace users
  3  temporary tablespace temp
  4  quota unlimited on users;

User created.

SQL> grant create session to mike;

Grant succeeded.
```

Connect as newly created user, try to select from `dba_tab_columns`:

```
SQL> connect mike/lion
Connected.
SQL> select count(*) from dba_tab_columns where table_name = 'DEPT';
select count(*) from dba_tab_columns where table_name = 'DEPT'
                     *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Doesn't work (as expected). Acquire some privileges and try again:

```
SQL> connect sys as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> grant select on dba_tab_columns to mike;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> connect  mike/lion
Connected.
SQL> select count(*) from dba_tab_columns where table_name = 'DEPT';

  COUNT(*)
----------
         6

SQL>
```

Now it works.

---

So ... yes, I agree with you - unless you have privileges to access `dba_tab_columns`,  how are you supposed to query it?

Comment: thank you for complete explanation and for confirming my understanding

Comment: `SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE` will do it.